# Error: Bool is not Convertible to Void:

Tags: swift, closures, ios8

I am moving my code from Obj. C to Swift C and trying to implementing the Twitter sdk..

But, I am getting an error... 
Can any body tell me what I have done wrong.

[image]

Please help me with this.

I spent 2 days tried everything but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your block does not have a return statement, therefore the compiler
uses the result of the last statement

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

as return value, which is a `Bool` and not `Void` as declared in the block signature.

To solve that problem, just add a return statement:

```
{ (url: NSURL, oauthToken: String) -> Void in
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `openURL` returns a boolean, and an attempt to convert it to `Void` is made, since the closure is declared as returning a `Void`. Simply remove that as follows:

```
{ (url: NSURL, token: String)  in
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}
```

If you don't want to change the closure signature, just assign the return value to a variable:

```
{ (url: NSURL, token: String) -> Void in
    let ret = UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}
```

Comment: ... or add `return` as last statement in the block.

Answer (score 0):

What's not stated in the other answers is that Swift will implicitly add a return to a single statement closure.

This is how statements like `conditionSet.sort {$0.set < $1.set}` can work.

This can also result in an unexpected error. To avoid the error, make the closure have 2 statements. The simplest way is to add a return after your original statement as stated in the accepted answer.